# how to compile sample code from Z3 under linux

Tags: z3

I downloaded z3 for linux version and was trying to make it work under linux but it fails to compile (i was compiling the example code using gcc). I got a list of undefined reference from gcc compiler. I believe I specified the lib file location when I was compiling the code.
Can anyone give what libraries that I need in order to make it compile correctly.

Answer (score 1):

Z3 for linux is compiled using

> gcc (Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3) 4.6.1

You may get linking errors if you are using an incompatible version of gcc.

Did you manage to compile the C example that comes with Z3?
It is located at: `z3/examples/c`

To compile it, you have to execute

> ./build.sh

If it doesn't work, it is probably because you are using an incompatible version of GCC.

Comment: Yeah, I did execute build.sh but my gcc compiler throws "skipping incompatible..." error and couldn't find -lz3-gmp. I checked my gcc version it is (gcc Ubuntu/Linaro 4.6.1-9ubuntu3)

Comment: my gcc is x64 so I downloaded z3 for x64 version, but when execute build.sh I get a list of undefined reference.

Comment: I see. Could you try to compile using:

Comment: `gcc -fopenmp -o test_capi test_capi.c -I ../../include -L ../../lib -lz3`

Comment: I rewrote the build.sh gcc -fopenmp -I../../include -L../../lib test_capi.c -lz3 -lgmp -o test_capi  and it compiles. But gcc needs libgmp.so.3 and i have libgmp.so.10 installed on my system. so the compiled code failed to load library.

Comment: The good news is that Z3 4.0 does not depend on gmp anymore. So, the problem will not happen in the next version.

Answer (score 1):

In xubuntu 11.10 (same gcc version), I moved `-lz3-gmp` to the **end** after `test_capi.c`. This is not the first time gcc threw up on me because `-l` was not at the end.

`gcc -fopemmp -o test_capi -I ../../include -L ../../lib test_capi.c -lz3-gmp`

And it works fine.